# How to write a temporal worker Interceptor class in Temporal Python-SDK

Tags: python, python-3.x, temporal-workflow

I am trying to implement an interceptor class for our temporal workflows written in Python. But since the documentation is not completely available, I have tried multiple ways to achieve it. But no success till now.

Below are some sample code for the temporal activities, workflows, interceptor class, worker and workflow executor.

*activities.py*

```py
from temporalio import activity


@activity.defn
async def activity1():
    print("Hi from activity 1")

@activity.defn
async def activity2():
    print("Hi from activity 2")
```

*workflow.py*

```py
from datetime import timedelta
from temporalio import workflow


with workflow.unsafe.imports_passed_through():
    from mactivities import activity1, activity2


@workflow.defn
class MyWorkflow1:

    @workflow.run
    async def run(self):
        output = await workflow.execute_activity(activity1, start_to_close_timeout=timedelta(5))
        return True



@workflow.defn
class MyWorkflow2:

    @workflow.run
    async def run(self):
        output = await workflow.execute_activity(activity2, start_to_close_timeout=timedelta(5))
        return True
```

*my_interceptor.py*

```py
from temporalio.worker import Interceptor


class MyInterceptor(Interceptor):  # NEED HELP IN THIS CLASS
    def __init__(self, next):
        super().__init__(next)

    async def intercept_activity(self, input):
        print("I am printing before activity execution start")
        return await.self.next.intercept_activity(input)

    async workflow_interceptor_class(self, input):
        print("Doing something before a workflow execution start")
        return None
```

*run_workflows.py*

```py
import asyncio
from temporalio.client import Client
from workflows import MyWorkflow1, MyWorkflow2

async def main():
    client = await Client.connect("localhost:7233")

    await client.execute_workflow(
                  MyWorkflow1.run,
                  id="123",
                  task_queue="MY_QUEUE"
                   )

    await client.execute_workflow(
                  MyWorkflow2.run,
                  id="123",
                  task_queue="MY_QUEUE"
                   )
    return True


if __name__=="__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

*run_worker.py*

```py
import asyncio
from temporalio.client import Client
from temporalio.worker import Worker

from activities import activity1, activity2
from workflow import MyWorkflow1, MyWorkflow2
from my_interceptor import MyInterceptor  # <--- NEED HELP IN IMPLEMENTING THIS CLASS

async def main():
    client = await Client.connect("localhost:7233")
    worker = Worker(
             client,
             task_queue="MY_QUEUE",
             workflows=[MyWorkflow1, MyWorkflow2],
             activities=[activity1, activity2],
             interceptors=[MyInterceptor]  # <--- NEED HELP IN IMPLEMENTING THIS CLASS
              )
     await worker.run()


if __name__=="__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

If I use the Interceptor class I wrote, I am getting exceptions. e.g. workflow_interceptor_class required a parameter "input", but while the worker initialized, it is not available. My activities are failing with a message "Completing activity as failed" etc.

Basically the way of implementation of the interceptor class in wrong.

**What I want to achieve ?**

1. Print the name of the workflow before starting the execution of that workflow.
2. I will keep some informations (arguments passed while executing) in a variable for future use.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you may want to have a look at the following for examples on how to implement Activity and Workflow interceptors in the Temporal Python SDK:

- [A sample](https://github.com/temporalio/samples-python/blob/f6a954ef0a503eb0721700c4f95f9f2cbff3eebf/sentry/interceptor.py#L71) from the Temporal's Python samples repository;
- [Interceptors test file](https://github.com/temporalio/sdk-python/blob/e1d983e226d055424a6c3404651079b23a44f5f0/tests/worker/test_interceptor.py#L34) from the Temporal Python SDK's test suit;
- [The OpenTelemetry Interceptor](https://github.com/temporalio/sdk-python/blob/e1d983e226d055424a6c3404651079b23a44f5f0/temporalio/contrib/opentelemetry.py#L293) from the Contribution directory in the Temporal Python SDK repo (note that this last one is significantly more complicated than the other two).

Based on code snippets you provided, I think you may have missed a very important detail: the implementation of `Interceptor` that you provide to `Worker` will not actually handle the interception of Workflow/Activity calls by itself.

Instead, the `Interceptor` object you provide will be used to build a chain of concrete interceptors. The responsibility of your `Interceptor` class are thus the following:

- `intercept_activity()`: Instantiate, chain and return an object that extends `ActivityInboundInterceptor`; simply return `next` if you do not want to intercept activities;
- `workflow_interceptor_class()`: Return a class that extends `WorkflowInboundInterceptor`; return `None` if you do not want to intercept Workflows.

Consequently, the complete implementation of an Interceptor will generally contain two or three classes, which could for example be named as so:

- `MyInterceptor` which extends `Interceptor`
- `MyActivityInboundInterceptor` which extends `ActivityInboundInterceptor`
- `MyWorkflowInboundInterceptor` which extends `WorkflowInboundInterceptor`

A simple implementation of `MyInterceptor` would look something like this:

```
class MyInterceptor(Interceptor):
    def intercept_activity(
        self, next: ActivityInboundInterceptor
    ) -> ActivityInboundInterceptor:
        return MyActivityInboundInterceptor(next)

    def workflow_interceptor_class(
        self, input: WorkflowInterceptorClassInput
    ) -> Optional[Type[WorkflowInboundInterceptor]]:
        return MyWorkflowInboundInterceptor
```

Now, that being said, I think the rest of it should fall into place much more easily, but just add a comment if you need more details on something.

> By the way, you may think that all this gymnastic is unintuitive, complex and
> useless, but let's not stop at this and just accept that there are
> strong reasons for this.

Comment: Thanks James. Those simple examples helped me a lot. Do you have any examples of intercepting the gRPC calls from the temporal worker to the temporal server? So basically I want to add some metadata in the header on every request my worker sends to the server e.g. While registering the worker, polling for tasks, etc.

Comment: You can't intercept gRPC calls from the Worker connection in Python, as the Worker connection is actually handled by Core SDK (ie. Rust code that is compiled to native and used behind the scene by the Python, TS, .Net, and Ruby SDKs).

Comment: You may still provide gRPC headers at connection time, using [the `rpc_metadata` property](https://github.com/temporalio/sdk-python/blob/main/temporalio/client.py#LL128C13-L128C25)

Comment: You may also attach per-call headers from the Activity/Workflow interceptors (for most intercepted methods), by adding them to `input.headers`. Search for `headers` in [this](https://github.com/temporalio/sdk-python/blob/main/temporalio/worker/_interceptor.py) to see where that is usable. The OpenTelemetry interceptor I linked to previously make extensive use of such headers.